# Plutus Pioneers Week 01 - How to open EnglishAuction shell?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I was wondering how to get the EnglishAuction shell open so I can run these commands from the first lecture?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Basically you should follow instructions for [Excercise Week 01](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program#exercises) in order to: setup the plutus repo, nix, cache, etc, as Mitchell said.

> - Clone the The Plutus repository, check out the correct commit as specified in cabal.project.
> - Install NixOS cross-referencing the following resources.
> - Set-up IOHK binary caches How to set up the IOHK binary caches. "If you do not do this, you will end up building GHC, which takes several hours. If you find yourself building GHC, STOP and fix the cache."

Then:

- `cd /your-repo/plutus`
- `nix-shell`
- `cd /your-repo/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01`
- `cabal repl`

Answer (score 1):

That would be the Cabal REPL. The command is `cabal repl`.

You need to be sure you are in the correct context for this to work. If you haven't done that, I'd recommend following the Nix setup instructions in the [Plutus repo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus). Once you have `nix-shell` running you can switch to the Pioneer Program repo and run `cabal repl`.

[Here](https://giters.com/adacapo21/plutusPioneerProgram) are some additional community-made instructions that can help fill in the gaps, but I don't think it covers some important stuff like the *cache*, so I'd start with the official docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Finally worked after I followed the Github steps about the IOHK binary caches